# MessageBox.Show wont appear when user inputs integers

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, integer

I am making a basic program for school and there is a textbox which the user inputs their postal code and the program is supposed to display a message box stating how much the shipping will cost based on the postal code inputted. But when I try to implement this code, type in my text in the text box and press the submit button the message box does not show up. But on the other hand when I make the program show a text box when there is anything that is NOT an integer it will work fine, for example:

```
                if (textBox1.Text.TrimStart() == string.Empty)
                    MessageBox.Show("A postal code is required");
```

Will work fine, showing the message box and so will

```
                if (textBox1.Text == "test")
                    MessageBox.Show("working");
```

But if there are any integers involved the program will do NOTHING, not even give any errors which is what makes this difficult to solve. Such as this:

```
                if (textBox1.Text == postcode2string)
                    MessageBox.Show("The cost of shipping is $15");
```

I have tried seperating the the code in braces instead of all in one chunk like so:

```
            {
                if (textBox1.Text == postcode1string)
                    MessageBox.Show("The shipping cost is $25");
            }
            {
                if (textBox1.Text == postcode2string)
                    MessageBox.Show("The cost of shipping is $15");
            }
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.TrimStart() == string.Empty)
                    MessageBox.Show("A postal code is required");
            }
            {
                if (textBox1.Text == "test")
                    MessageBox.Show("working");
            }
```

but the same problem still remains I have also tried using else statements too like so

```
            if (textBox1.Text.TrimStart() == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A postal code is required");
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text == postcode1string);
                MessageBox.Show("The shipping cost is $25");
            }
```

but that also does not work at all, I have even converted my integers into strings like such:

```
            int postcode1 = 0 - 999;
            int postcode2 = 1000 - 1999;
            int postcode3 = 2000 - 2999;
            int postcode4 = 3000 - 3999;
            int postcode5 = 4000 - 4999;
            int postcode6 = 5000 - 5999;
            int postcode7 = 6000 - 6999;
            int postcode8 = 7000 - 7999;
            string postcode1string = postcode1.ToString();
            string postcode2string = postcode2.ToString();
            string postcode3string = postcode3.ToString();
            string postcode4string = postcode4.ToString();
            string postcode5string = postcode5.ToString();
            string postcode6string = postcode6.ToString();
            string postcode7string = postcode7.ToString();
            string postcode8string = postcode8.ToString();
```

Which you can also guess, still doesn't work. All my problems give no errors, nothing happens at all. I am truly lost.
The full code for the program is:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int postcode1 = 0 - 999;
            int postcode2 = 1000 - 1999;
            int postcode3 = 2000 - 2999;
            int postcode4 = 3000 - 3999;
            int postcode5 = 4000 - 4999;
            int postcode6 = 5000 - 5999;
            int postcode7 = 6000 - 6999;
            int postcode8 = 7000 - 7999;
            string postcode1string = postcode1.ToString();
            string postcode2string = postcode2.ToString();
            string postcode3string = postcode3.ToString();
            string postcode4string = postcode4.ToString();
            string postcode5string = postcode5.ToString();
            string postcode6string = postcode6.ToString();
            string postcode7string = postcode7.ToString();
            string postcode8string = postcode8.ToString();

            if (textBox1.Text.TrimStart() == string.Empty)
                MessageBox.Show("A postal code is required");
            if (textBox1.Text == postcode1string)
                MessageBox.Show("The shipping cost is $25");
            if (textBox1.Text == postcode2string)
                MessageBox.Show("The cost of shipping is $15");
        }
```

Comment: All of your postal codes end up "-999". I don't think that is what you really want.

Comment: With c#9 patterns (and some dummy values/cases elided): `var shipCost = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) switch { < 1000 => 25, < 2000 => 15, < 3000 => 10, _ => 0 }; MessageBox.Show($"Shipping cost is {shipCost:C0}");` or something like that. Though it's very weird to treat postal codes as Integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare your ints like that. What you really doing is that the first int Postcode1 is equal to 0 minus 999. So its -999 and when you try to say that if for example the postcode 555 equals to the int it won't because 555 =! 999.

A way to do this is in the if statement, you need to make two conditions. If it's bigger than 0 and smaller than 999. You could also declare a variable for the textbox text which will be and int and then compare this in in the if statements. Like this:

```
        try{
            int postalcode = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        }
        catch{
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide a number")
        }
        
        
        if (postalcode > 0 && postalcode < 999)
            MessageBox.Show("The shipping cost is $25");
        if (postalcode > 1000 && postalcode < 1999)
            MessageBox.Show("The cost of shipping is $15");
```